# Visual Studio for Mac. Warning. Xcode 10.0 is currently selected in preferences and is incompatible with the version of Xamarin.ios being used

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, warnings

Warning: "Xcode 10.0 is currently selected in Preferences and is incompatible with the version of Xamarin.ios being used. This may cause unexpected errors or warnings while building and deploying the project. To resolve this, go to Preferences and select a version of Xcode that is at least as new as Xcode 10.1".

Help me please. Where can I change version?

Comment: I wonder if there's an easy way to change Visual Studio version to match the Xcode you do have installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have Visual Studio for Mac 7.7 (build 1868).  I found a setting under

Preferences -> Projects -> SDK Locations -> Apple

for the Apple SDK.

(At first I did not realize that I had to open the SDK Locations item to see the Apple sub-item underneath it.)

My entry for Apple SDK was set to /Applications/XCode.app

Looks like Visual Studio deduces the XCode version number from the properties of the XCode.app file.

(After I updated XCode to version 10.1, I had to Restart Visual Studio for the change to take effect.)

Comment: I was searching under the project preferences... never thought about the application preferences. Thank you!